# Writing List value to an Excel

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a list with values as Below:

```
print(list_Theme)
print(list_SubTheme)
print(list_Quote)

['Operating environment', 'Competitive advantage']
['Regional Demand', None]
["In China Cash flow from operating activities was $670 million, up 19%.ABB's regional and country order trends for the third quarter are illustrated on Slide 4.", 'Specifically, in the United States, our largest market, Electrification order growth was robust apart from large orders, whichhad a tough comparison base.']
```

I want the output in an excel like below:
    [image]

I have written the below script but can someone point out how to implement the same?

```
 import xlsxwriter
 outWorkbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook("out.xlsx")
 outSheet=outWorkbook.add_worksheet()
 outSheet.write("A1","Theme")
 outSheet.write("B1","Sub-Theme")
 outSheet.write("C1","Quote")
 #row=0
 #col=0
 #I am stuck here on how to proceed? Should I use write_row? or Is there a better way?


 outWorkbook.close()
```

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a DataFrame
lists = {
    'list_Theme':['Operating environment', 'Competitive advantage'],
    'list_SubTheme':['Regional Demand', None],

       'list_Quote':["In China Cash flow from operating activities was $670 million, up 19%.ABB's regional and country order trends for the third quarter are illustrated on Slide 4.", 'Specifically, in the United States, our largest market, Electrification order growth was robust apart from large orders, whichhad a tough comparison base.']}

df = pd.DataFrame(lists,columns=['list_Theme','list_SubTheme','list_Quote'])

df.to_excel(r'Path where you want to store the exported excel file\File Name.xlsx')
```

Comment: this worked very well. I have changed the way the you have merged the lists. import pandas as pd
lists = [list_Theme,list_SubTheme,list_Quote]
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in lists], axis=1)
df.columns = ['Theme', 'Sub-Theme', 'Quote']
#print(df)
df.to_excel(r'out.xlsx',index=False)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write into the Excel Files, but as you are using xlsxwriter; let me use the same approach for you.

**You can try this code:**

```
import xlsxwriter

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']

data = [{'Theme':'Operating environment','Sub-Theme': 'Regional Demand','Quote':'In China Cash flow from operating activities was $670 million, up 19%.ABB\'s regional and country order trends for the third quarter are illustrated on Slide 4.'},{'Theme':'Competitive advantage','Sub-Theme': 'None','Quote':'Specifically, in the United States, our largest market, Electrification order growth was robust apart from large orders, which had a tough comparison base.'}]

FileName="Output.xlsx"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(FileName)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

header_col_name=['Theme','Sub-Theme','Quote']
for i in header_col_name:
      worksheet.write(''+letters[header_col_name.index(i)]+'1', i, bold)
i=2
for d in data:
     for j in header_col_name:
          worksheet.write(''+letters[header_col_name.index(j)]+ str(i), d[j])
     i=i+1
workbook.close()
```